# Lucene.NET - check if document exists in index

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I want to check whether or not a document already exists in my Lucene.NET (4.0) index. I have tried using the following code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714288/condition-to-check-whether-document-exists-in-index-lucene-net).

```
IndexReader reader;
Term indexTerm = new Term("filepath", "C:\\my\\path");
TermDocs docs = reader.TermDocs(indexTerm);
if (docs.Next())
{
    continue;
}
```

But I get an error telling me that `reader` is unassigned. I have Googled this a lot and cannot find a working answer in Lucene.NET 4 for what should be quite an easy task.

**edit**: `IndexReader` is an abstract class. In the documentation it says to call `IndexReader.Open()` with `Lucene.Net.Store.Directory` as a parameter, but it itself is abstract. Code samples that I get use it as if it were not. Moreover, in the post I linked to the user said the first segment of code worked.

**EDIT2:** I now have code that compiles. Here it is:

```
bool exists = false;
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(lucenePath), false);
Term term = new Term("filepath", "\\myFile.PDF");
TermDocs docs = reader.TermDocs(term);
if (docs.Next())
{
   exists = true;
}
```

The file `myFile.PDF` definitely exists, but it always comes back as false. When I look at `docs` in debug, its `Doc` and `Freq` properties state that they "threw an exception of type '`System.NullReferenceException`'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lucene.NET - checking if document exists in index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993676/lucene-net-checking-if-document-exists-in-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set `reader` to be anything. You need to initialise it before using it. You can do this is you have the path of the index using:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(indexDirectoryPath);
```

or:

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(indexDirectoryPath);
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(directory);
```

or:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(indexDirectoryPath);
Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(directoryInfo);
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(directory);
```

where `indexDirectoryPath` in all cases is the full path of the index location as a `string`. Which way you use depends on which version of Lucene.Net you are using.

Additionally, make sure that you close the reader when you have finished with it (by calling `reader.Close()`), otherwise you will likely get file locking issues.

Comment: IndexReader.Open() does not have an overload that takes just a string. For me there are 5 overloads, one of which accepts a Lucene.Net.Store.Directory(), which itself I cannot instantiate. I have edited my original post with more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help Adrian. I have now got code that compiles, but am still having difficulties. I have updated the question.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I would ask that edit as a new question. Questions on StackOverflow should be self contained about one specific issue, otherwise they tend to get either down-voted or closed.

Comment: Incidentally, take a look at [luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/). It enables you to browse the contents of your index in a UI. You should be able to check that what you expect is in the index is actually there.

Comment: Will do, thankyou. I have created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993676/lucene-net-checking-if-document-exists-in-index and will upvote / 'answer' your question if you can help.