# Lucene : Check Index availability before

Tags: java, lucene

I would like to know if there are ways to check the Index availability before creating it. I referred a lot of threads like : [Lucene.NET - check if document exists in index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992372/lucene-net-check-if-document-exists-in-index) . But, my program didn't work.

I am using the TutorialsPoint example to implement this with Java 1.5.

Below is a little code snippet which I used :

LuceneTester.java

```
static String indexDir = "D:\\Lucene\\Index";
    static String dataDir = "D:\\Lucene\\Data";
```

Main :

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(directory);
              Term term = new Term("D:\\Lucene\\Data","record1.txt");
              TermDocs docs = reader.termDocs(term);

              if(docs.next()){
                  System.out.println("Already Indexed");
              }else{
                  tester = new LuceneTester();
                  tester.createIndex();
                  tester.search("Anish");
              }
```

Comment: The first argument to the `Term` ctor should be the name of the field ("filename", for instance).

Comment: @femtoRgon Thank you.